# iOS 7 weird button on a html submit input

Tags: javascript, css, html, ios7

Im building an HTML5 Phonegap app for iOS. This submit button is a normal html input submit like this:

```
<input type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" name="email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
<input class="signin" type="submit" value="Sign in">

  .signin {
        padding: inherit;
        background: #006ad9;
        width: 243px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 0px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
```

This si how it looks on the iOS similator:

[image]

Even those input text's are rounded, my CSS has no such style for it!

Why is this happening?

Comment: Ok, changine input type submit to a button fixed this. Inoput type submit is not valid html. But why the rounded inputs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
input[type=submit] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Put this at the top of the css and then set styles for your classes

Comment: Awesome, this worked! Always great to learn these little css tricks

Comment: This is what i do to reset weird style in Safari mobile too.. but I set it to all `input` types like... `input {....}`